# how can I check if my webservice is sending the data compressed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, compression

How I know if my server is sending the data compress or not.

```
ajaxMap = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/GTracker/Cars/CarTreeDetails2',
            data: { "id": carTreeSelectedID },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                showCarData(data);
            }
        });
```

Using fiddler the response say 170k if select GZIP get reduce to 30k. So not sure if is responsibilit of server/client to send/ask for compress data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshots the data is not compressed.

In case of a compressed result you should get this in the response:

[image]

And you can check the `headers` tab of the response:

[image]

Comment: so my ajax call is ok, i dont have to do anything else to receive compress data? the problem is on the server side? My headers doesnt have `Transport` information

Comment: Yes, the request seems ok. You should check the server (web server or your code) to see how to handle the compression of the data.

Comment: im using C#, my function end with `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: I'm not sure regarding C#, but I think you might wanna set this in the server configuration (iis?)

Comment: yes, IIS. I include `<httpCompression>
     <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />       
     </dynamicTypes>
   </httpCompression>`

Comment: Will appreciate it if you can approve an voteup the answer, unless it is not the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [**TOOL**](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/) make easy check what resources are beign compress and not.

And **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088321/why-my-html-is-compress-but-my-json-isnt)** is how I make my `JSON` compressed.

[image]